# PostgreSQL doesn't recognize function called from Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a function in PostgreSQL:

```
func(a integer, b integer)
```

When I call the function from Python:

```
"select * from func(%s,%s)"(a_1,b_1)
```

It works if `a_1` and `b_1` are integers.
However there can be a case where `b_1` is `None`. In this case I get this error message:

> Exception: ERROR:  column "none" does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...func(38,None)

I know that None in Python is equivalent to PostgreSQL NULL, but in this case I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Is it possible that `a_1` or `b_1` is anything other than an integer?  Say, a string?  Particularly a string such as [`'); DROP TABLE Something --'`](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Kevin a_1 and b_1 data is received from integer fields in other DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"select * from func(%s,%s)" % (a_1, 'NULL' if b_1 == None else b_1)
```